# How to create primary index to a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have a 50,000,000 row `csv` file .

```
name,  salary, text
anna,  100,   good
mary,  50,    low
amber, 60,    ok
   ...........
```

I need to add primary index `p_index`

```
p_index,  name,  salary, text
1,        anna,  100,   good
2,        mary,  50,    low
3,        amber, 60,    ok
       ...........
```

So far I use `BufferedReader`  read line by line . And then copy  with `PrintWriter` from the original csv to a new csv . However this approach is slow  . .  around 20 minutes . Is there any way to add auto increment values faster . Here is my code

```
public class Test {
    static PrintWriter pw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.csv");
        File file = new File("test2.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = reader.readLine();
        pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        pw.println("P_INDEX," + line);

        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            pw.println(i + "," + line);
            i++;
        }

        pw.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Can anybody make corrections to my code to improve it to work faster ?

Thanks

Comment: It can be optimized, but in any case it will be a variation of your approach. Post the code

Comment: I have posted my code . . I created a static PrintWriter because i wanted to create multiple threads  but i think there must be an easier way

Comment: It took 36 seconds to run your code on a 900Mb file with 50M lines and filled with your sample data

Comment: @basin That's probably with fairly high end disk and CPU, and enough memory, and no other disk-intensive operations happening at the same time. And real data is probably with many more fields. Adding a multiplier for some of these, it's easy to get to 30 times longer run time.

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA It would be helpful to know how large your data file is. Maybe you're going to be limited by how fast you can write data to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities.

1. Benchmark any change, do methodical "binary search" for optimal buffer sizes etc. Use a smaller file for this, something which is processed in some dozens of seconds.
2. Do not use `String`, use only raw byte arrays. Conversion between 8-bit char encoding of the file and 16 bit unicode of Java chars is a performance killer in a bulk data case like this (but watch for [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of file, if there's one insert first bytes after it).
3. If you have a regularly formatted CSV file with fixed columns, there is minimum line length. You can skip this many bytes when scanning the buffer for next row.
4. Use [`java.nio`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O)
5. Optimize buffer size (see item 1. above).
6. Read to next buffer while processing previous, with 2 threads. Perhaps put writing to third thread (in this case scanning is probably irrelevant to performance, no point skipping parts of rows).

Comment: It takes 5 seconds on my computer to call Integer.toString() 50M times

Comment: @basin I'm not sure what you mean, but the string item in answer refers to passing gigabytes of 8-bit text to character codec to get 2X gigabytes of Java strings, then passing it back through codec to again get 1X gigabytes of 8-bit text.

Answer (score 0):

By default a PrintWriter has a fairly small buffer. You will probably improve performance making sure you use create the PrintWriter with a BufferedWriter with a larger buffer. For example:

```
new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), 1000000));
```

If you've got an idea of how large your data set is going to be you can also set the buffer size for both your reader and writer to reduce the number of reads/writes to disk.

Using an example file of ~4Gb and your example code writing took  ~53 seconds. Using the same input file with a BufferedWriter and using a 10Mb buffer writing took ~48 seconds

Comment: No. The constructor PrintWriter(File) already creates BufferedWriter

Comment: @basin I've updated my answer based on your comment. Thank you.